# I just cannot get my app to resize itself on different screen sizes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I am completely new to iOS development (and making apps in general). I do not understand at all how to use the Storyboard to create an app. I am basically trying to copy what I have wriiten for Android and turn it into an iOS app, but the app won't resize the view on different screen sizes. Android was really easy for me to do, and I just feel like I'm drowning with iOS.

iOS xml:

```
<!--Login Screen-->
    <scene sceneID="4za-P4-q9T">
        <objects>
            <viewController title="Login Screen" id="MtT-4F-W33" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="NEA-R9-GOJ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="right" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="Hw4-rM-kL1">
                            <rect key="frame" x="260" y="506" width="121" height="33"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="AvenirNext-Regular" family="Avenir Next" pointSize="15"/>
                            <state key="normal" title="Forgot Password?">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.33333334329999997" green="0.33333334329999997" blue="0.33333334329999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" red="0.5" green="0.5" blue="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" layoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth="YES" text="Canvas Grades" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uqo-Xm-Ohe">
                            <rect key="frame" x="31" y="197" width="211" height="24"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <directionalEdgeInsets key="directionalLayoutMargins" top="8" leading="8" bottom="8" trailing="8"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="semibold" pointSize="20"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.50980392159999999" green="0.44705882349999998" blue="0.31372549020000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" layoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth="YES" text="Highlands Latin School" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Rl8-LJ-hBJ">
                            <rect key="frame" x="31" y="140" width="350" height="60"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <directionalEdgeInsets key="directionalLayoutMargins" top="8" leading="8" bottom="8" trailing="8"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="heavy" pointSize="25"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.1333333333" blue="0.25098039220000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" layoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth="YES"/>
                        </label>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="6KG-IA-18I">
                            <rect key="frame" x="31" y="813" width="350" height="49"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.1333333333" blue="0.25098039220000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="AvenirNext-DemiBold" family="Avenir Next" pointSize="24"/>
                            <state key="normal" title="Login">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.50980392159999999" green="0.44705882349999998" blue="0.31372549020000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" red="0.5" green="0.5" blue="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" layoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Email" minimumFontSize="17" clearButtonMode="whileEditing" id="meL-FW-06U">
                            <rect key="frame" x="31" y="431" width="350" height="34"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="tintColor" red="0.0" green="0.1333333333" blue="0.25098039220000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <edgeInsets key="layoutMargins" top="8" left="8" bottom="8" right="8"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.1333333333" blue="0.25098039220000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Password" minimumFontSize="17" id="n7w-gQ-knJ">
                            <rect key="frame" x="32" y="473" width="350" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                    <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="4yK-Ux-bpz"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="WjO-MG-iyw" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="62.318840579710148" y="1017.8571428571428"/>
    </scene>
```

Sorry if this is a really noob question but I looked online and even used templates to help me figure this out but I just can't! The constraints and how to add them and use multipliers make no sense to me. If the view was a picture, I just want it to be dragged from the corner to resize horizontally and vertically but leave all the elements in the same relative place (element at the bottom on an SE should be at the bottom on Pro Max). Thank you!

Comment: "I do not understand at all how to use the Storyboard to create an app" - I recommend reading some tutorials, for instance this one: https://matteomanferdini.com/ios-storyboards-xcode/

Answer (score 1):

> element at the bottom on an SE should be at the bottom on Pro Max

Well, let's take that as an example.

You could use auto layout. In that case that element needs a constraint from its bottom to the bottom of its superview. That takes care of its vertical position. It also needs to be given enough constraints to determine its size and its horizontal position.

Alternatively you could use autoresizing. In that case you want struts at the bottom and either the right or left.